# Two difference coefficients for the same variable in my OLS regression

Tags: regression, linear-regression, coefficients

I'm using a multiple regression to look for a relationship between US senators' budget requests and the industries from which they tend to receive contributions. I'm including several potential confounders, one of which is senators' state size. Senators are given a state size code of either S, M, or L. In my coefficient table, however, I'm getting two "size S" coefficients in addition to an "M" coefficient, and they're different from one another. Can anyone tell me why this is happening/how to interpret this and/or if I've simply made some sort of error?

Here's the full coefficient table (sorry that the variable names look so messy!):

```
                                      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
```

(Intercept)                                        25.723     37.728   0.682   0.5022
aggregaterevised$number_ones_contributors          2.204      3.266   0.675   0.5066
aggregaterevised$partyIDR                  -34.380     19.767  -1.739   0.0954 .
aggregaterevised$statesizeM                 13.486     20.799   0.648   0.5232
aggregaterevised$statesizeS                 16.255     26.902   0.604   0.5516
aggregaterevised$statesizeS                 -3.282     48.387  -0.068   0.9465
aggregaterevised$purple_divergentY          21.827     21.150   1.032   0.3128
aggregaterevised$celebrityY                 18.777     23.280   0.807   0.4282
aggregaterevised$seniorY                    -4.272     17.700  -0.241   0.8114

Residual standard error: 44.46 on 23 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.3032,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.06077
F-statistic: 1.251 on 8 and 23 DF,  p-value: 0.3157

and here's my original code:

lm(aggregaterevised$number_ones_requests ~ aggregaterevised$number_ones_contributors + aggregaterevised$partyID + aggregaterevised$statesize + aggregaterevised$purple_divergent + aggregaterevised$celebrity + aggregaterevised$senior)

Thanks so much!